# Webservices to create or modify (the metadata of) a document

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services

I'm using SharePoint online.

I need to do some validations before create the document for example I have to validate if a value A exists in a list B before allowing the user to upload a document or modify the metadata through the webservices.

Can you give an idea to do this? Can I create a middle step between the request and the action itself? Can I limit the use of the webservice?